# How To Do Direct Conversion From One Number Base To A New Number Base

Tags: radix, base-conversion, number-systems

I want to understand direct conversion from one number base to a different number base. What are the steps that work for any number base to another number base? What I am looking for is not a short cut method which works for say, binary to octal or hexa-decimal number system. It can be anything like converting number base-22 to base-37.

I don't want any explanation that converts to base-10 first & then do the conversion to the destination number base. I already understand it. The direct conversion steps (if they exist) with a short explanation would be really helpful. I am really trying to get my head around it.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for [ComputerScience.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty heavy topic. The steps do exist. You can do conversion between any two number systems. But you will be doing arithmetic calculation in a different number base. That itself is pretty hard to get your head around it.

I can quote the general concept behind direct base conversion from [a W3 Spot article](https://www.w3spot.com/2020/08/direct-conversion-from-any-number-base-to-another-base-explained.html):

> 1. Divide the number by the value of other base.
> 2. Get the remainder. That is the least significant digit.
> 3. Divide the quotient with the value of other base.
> 4. Add the remainder as next least significant digit.
>
> We need to keep doing steps 3 & 4 repeatedly till quotient becomes
> zero.

But that's not all. There are subtle nuances when you convert from lower to higher base than the opposite way. Let's say, you are doing base-3 to base-6 conversion. You will have to do some arithmetic operation on the base-3 number. And all the calculation will be done in base-3 number system. How do we convert to base-6 number then? base-3 system doesn't have 3, 4 & 5 digits that are valid in base-6 system. You need to have a mapping first between base-3 digits & base-6 digits.

Also doing division in non-decimal number system is not easy. If you do it using pen & paper, you should create multiplication table in that number system.

All these things are not easy. That's why we convert to decimal system first. Anyways just go through the article I mentioned above. It explains the steps in details with examples for both lower to higher base & the opposite.

Comment: I am  going to check the link.

Comment: I got the concept. I tried with new examples of my own & was able to convert following the article. But it is not easy. I am not sure if we have any other methods to do this. For now, I am good. It works.

Comment: Good to know that you have some clarity. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted & upvote :)

Comment: Forgot to do that! New here.